# Как создать перегруженную функцию в golang?

Tags: golang

Как сделать, что б одна функция и та же могла принимать разного типа параметры?
например, если она получает входящий параметр int то делается одно, если string-то другое.
например

```
func myfunc(??? ){
//какое-нибудь одинаковое действие для обоих вариантов
log.Println("Мне передали число,идём по пути 1")//или...
log.Println("Мне передали строку,идём по пути 2")
}
```

Или надо писать 2 разные функции?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Через пустой интерфейс и [свитч по типу](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches):

```
func f(v interface{}) {
    switch v.(type) {
    case int:
        fmt.Println("int", v)
    case string:
        fmt.Println("string", v)
    default:
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("f: unsupported type %T", v))
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/EUmI1N2OYp.